# CSS3 Transform, skew and rotate

Tags: css

I'm looking at CSS3 Transform and wanting to have a box, both skewed and rotated.

I've tried using:

```
transform:rotate(80deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(80deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(80deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(80deg); /* Opera */
-webkit-transform: skew(50deg);
-moz-transform:skew(50deg);
-o-transform:skew(50deg);
transform:skew(50deg);
```

This only seems to skew the div.

Can you use skew and rotate on the same div?

Thanks

Comment: use a comma between the transforms

Comment: Something like `-webkit-transform: skew(20deg), rotate(80deg)` ?

Comment: I thought so, but maybe not.

Comment: i tried: `-webkit-transform: skew(20deg) rotate(80deg);` which has seemed to work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of declaring the transforms more than once (the later rule always wins), you should separate your transforms by spaces like this:

```
transform: rotate(80deg) skew(20deg);
```

Don't forget all the vendor prefixes before this rule.

You can see the syntax on the [W3C's working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#effects)

Comment: Brilliant. I had a little bit of trial and error and managed to find the solution.